# How to group all sub categories of the duplicates under one category in a new array

Tags: javascript

I have an array that has duplicates of categories for example

array = { Category: "Ad-Based Monetization", SubCategory: "Content & Information Services"},
{ Category: "Balance sheet businesses", SubCategory: "test1"},
{ Category: "Balance sheet businesses", SubCategory: "test2"}

I want to be able to push the values of that array into a new array but in this following format:

array2 = {Category: "Balance sheet businesses", SubCategory: [{ name: "test1"},{name: "test2"}]},
{ Category: "Ad-Based Monetization", SubCategory: [{ name: "Content & Information Services"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should be enough to achieve what you want.

As always, there are much optimized ways to do the same than this but this should be enough to get you started and you can think about optimizations on your own.

```js
var array = [{ Category: "Ad-Based Monetization", SubCategory: "Content & Information Services"}, { Category: "Balance sheet businesses", SubCategory: "test1"}, { Category: "Balance sheet businesses", SubCategory: "test2"}]

var obj = {}

// Create a simple lookup with Category as key and SubCategories as value
array.forEach(arr => {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(arr.Category)){
        obj[arr.Category].push(arr.SubCategory);
    } else {
        obj[arr.Category] = [arr.SubCategory];
    }
});

const final = []

// Loop over the obj created and format it into the desired structure
for (let Category in obj){
    const SubCategory = obj[Category].map(name => ({name}));
    final.push({Category, SubCategory})
}

console.log(final);
```